# RESTful updates in Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For reasons that are beyond needing explanation here, I've had to create my own RESTful actions in my controller, such that there are four corresponding actions as one would expect:

x_create
x_read
x_update
x_delete

with their corresponding POST/GET/DELETE/PUT methods. I was wondering though, none of the documentation seems to suggest ways the UPDATE works if you create your own action:

```
def x_update
  X.update(params[:id], :par1 => params[:par1], :par2 => params[:par2])
end
```

will work, but what if :par2 used to contain a string and the update doesn't have it? Does REST dictate that the update must always have at least the original content, if it isn't modified? Or is there a better way than checking if params[:par2] is nil?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, when updating it is possible to "nullify" a field, as long as it is permitted by validations. If what you're meaning is that your action only receives a restricted set of params, update calls update_attributes, i think but i'm not sure that it only changes the params you give to it, so

```
X.update(params[:id], :par1 => "foo")
```

should update par1 and leave the rest of attributes alone,

```
X.update(params[:id], :par1 => nil)
```

should nullify par1. But i'm not 100% sure, you should give it a try using the console.

Comment: You're right about the first part, but is there a clean way to just create that request if params[:par2] is not set in the request? All I can think of something along the lines of switch cases.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ? it's not easy to answer without context. maybe something using update_all ? (see http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all) you'll still have to extract relevant parameters from params, though. If what you want is to make sure that the value is not nullified, you could build a hash first, stuff in all params that are not nil, and then do the update using the hash as argument